# Getting Paypal to redirect immediately

Tags: paypal

When the PayPal transaction is complete, PayPal shows this:

```
Thanks for your order
Your payment of $XXXX.XX USD is complete.
You're now going back to MYSITE.
If you are not redirected within 10 seconds, click here.
```

I don't want the buyer to wait for 10 seconds. How can I decrement this time to 0 second ?

Comment: Show us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I do not really know how to do !!! so i must post this question to stack overflow.